# Bundle a Set of Commands Into a Single Custom Command (Windows Command Prompt)

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a clone of a git repository nested in many subfolders, and it takes a while to cd through all of them in order to call git pull. Is there a way to create a custom command that just bundles all of the cd statements + git pull together for Windows CMD?

Answer (score 0):

A batch file would solve your problem, just call the commands one after another.

**cd_pull.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
cd D:/Projects/my_folder/my_other_folder/yet_another_folder/my_git_repo
git pull
```